# how to filter user created by another superuserso that it can send notice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

in my forms.py

```
class NoticeFormWarden(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Noticee
        fields = ('name','description','users','file',)

    def save(self,user):
        owner = user
        issue_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        users = self.cleaned_data['users']
        file = self.cleaned_data['file']

        Noticee.objects.create(name=name, description=description, users=users, file=file, owner=owner, issue_date=issue_date)

    def __init__(self, users, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoticeFormWarden, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['users'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_hostelstaff=True)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' Subject'
        self.fields['file'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' Subject'
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'write your msg here . . .'
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

in views.py

```
def WardenCreateNotice(request):
    form = NoticeFormWarden(request.user, request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Saved notice')
            form.save(request.user)
            form = NoticeFormWarden(request.user)
            return redirect("warden_view:notice-warden2")
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'warden_view/notice.html',context)
```

I have four type of user: admin,warden,staff,student

> admin creates warden
>
> warden creates staff
>
> staff creates student

Now i want send notice so that:

> admin sends notice to warden
>
> warden sends notice to their created staff

note that one warden has many staff and it can send notice **to its only staff**

How can I filter specific warden created staff?

Comment: specify your problem

Comment: @PrabuReddy i want to filter the staff user created by warden user

Comment: I see only the code _creating_ something, not filtering. You didn't show any models or querysets so it's hard to understand where and for what reason you're trying to "filter" those records. Also it's not clear whether you have a bunch of (co)related models or a single hierarchical model or whatever else. Please add details to your question.